# Pom tag <finalName> is not working correctly

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My project has pom.xml which builds up ear. I have added the finalName tag in pom.xml e.g. *test-ear-${parent.version}-${region}*. I am using following command -> mvn clean install **-Dregion=QA**. In my local workspace ear is formed with correct name as test-ear-3.5.23.0-QA.ear. However when it installs in the repository its build like test-3.5.23.0.ear. Means it is ignoring the finalName when installing in local repository.

What I understand is, maven is ignoring tag  and using ArtifactName + Version to build name of artifact. Also I am not able to override version of artifact test-ear, because I suppose I am using the relative path in parent tag. Here is my sample pom.xml:-

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
     <relativePath>../test-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>${pom.version}</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.proj.child</groupId>
<artifactId>test-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<build>
    <finalName>test-ear-${parent.version}-${region}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
    .................
```

It works for me if I provide artifact version and versions of all the dependencies for test-ear artifact. Can someone guide, what is wrong with my pom.

Comment: The `<finalName>..</finalName>` tag is only to change the name within the `target` directory. You can't change the naming convention for repositories. The rule for naming in the repository is `artifactId-VERSION.XXX` ...Furthermore the usage of `<version>${pom.version}</version>` will result in WARNINGs during the build and if you do an `install` or `deploy` with it this will result in unusable poms.

Comment: I am not able to override the version using version tag <version>test-ear-${parent.version}-${region}</version>  as I am using relative path in parent pom tag. If I mention versions in all the dependencies it works for me. But don't think that is ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the properties label? you must put the field in this label,then get it use ${fieldname}.

Comment: <properties>
  <pom.version>1.15.0</pom.version>
</properties> I have properties tag similar to above in my parent pom. I am Inheriting this version in multiple child pom to get the version.  In the artifact "test-ear" I want it be appened with the -Dregion in mentioned in command.